# How to use multiple seperate models in a razor view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, data-binding, view

I'm currently working on a project where I want to display 2 webgrid tables with each different models. I've found alot of tutorials how to use multiple models in a regular MVC View but it does not work in a Razor View. I'm kinda stuck on this now.

**What I've tried so far - 1**

Controller:

I've tried using an dynamic ExpandObject to add two lists to this View, look code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string sortApi = "ApiName",string sortCompany = "CompanyName", string sortdir = "asc", string search = "")
{
        int pageSize = 13;
        int totalRecords = 0;
        if (page < 1)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        int skip = (page * pageSize) - pageSize;
        ViewBag.TotalRows = totalRecords;
        ViewBag.search = search;

        //Dynamic ExpandObject
        var dataApiRedirects = getRedirects(search, sortApi, sortdir, skip, pageSize, out totalRecords);
        var dataCompanies = getCompanies(search, sortCompany, sortdir, skip, pageSize, out totalRecords);
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.ApiList = dataApiRedirects;
        mymodel.CompanyList = dataCompanies;

        return View(mymodel);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 d-flex align-items-stretch" style="padding-top: 5%;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+API</a>
                </div>
                <!--MODAL-->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" >
                    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 20%;">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                                <h3 class="modal-title">Add API</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form id="myForm">
                                    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model.ApiList.ApiName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })</p>
                                    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ApiList.First().Company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Company" })</p>
                                    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ApiList.First().ApiURL2, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "URL" })</p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                                <input type="reset" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </div>
```

However when I want to create textboxes in my modal im getting the following error:

[image]

**What I've tried so far - 2**

I've also tried using a ViewBag:

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string sortApi = "ApiName",string sortCompany = "CompanyName", string sortdir = "asc", string search = "")
{
        int pageSize = 13;
        int totalRecords = 0;
        if (page < 1)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        int skip = (page * pageSize) - pageSize;

        var dataApiRedirects = getRedirects(search, sortApi, sortdir, skip, pageSize, out totalRecords);
        var dataCompanies = getCompanies(search, sortCompany, sortdir, skip, pageSize, out totalRecords);
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.ApiList = dataApiRedirects;
        mymodel.CompanyList = dataCompanies;

        //Model 1 data
        ViewBag.CompaniesList = dataCompanies;


        ViewBag.TotalRows = totalRecords;
        ViewBag.search = search;

        //Model 2 data
        return View(mymodel);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
var getlist = ViewBag.CompaniesList as IEnumerable<APIBrokerFrontend.Models.Company>;

<div class="modal fade" id="myModalCompany">
                <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 20%;">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Add Company</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="myForm">
                                @<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(getlist.First().CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Company Name" })</p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                            <input type="reset" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Using ViewBag I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that an operation like `First()` is used. Correct way to use dynamic model is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views). Please correct your code to use index 0 (e.g. `ApiList[0]`) to get first element instead of  `First()`.

Example of using dynamic:

View:

```
@using Sample;

@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<a href="~/Default1">@Model.Blogs[0].MyCompany.CompanyName</a>
```

Controller:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public string Name;
    public string URL;
    public Company MyCompany;
}

public class MyModel
{
    public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
 public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public string Name;
    public string URL;
    public Company MyCompany;
}

public class MyModel
{
    public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    List<Blog> topBlogs = new List<Blog>
      { 
          new Blog { Name = "ScottGu", URL = "http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/", MyCompany = new Company{
              CompanyName = "Microsoft"
          }},
          new Blog { Name = "Scott Hanselman", URL = "http://www.hanselman.com/blog/", MyCompany = new Company{
              CompanyName = "Microsoft"
          }},
          new Blog { Name = "Jon Galloway", URL = "http://www.asp.net/mvc", MyCompany = new Company{
              CompanyName = "Microsoft"
          }}
      };

    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myModel = new MyModel();
        myModel.Blogs = topBlogs;

        return View(myModel);
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

You have to define the type of the view model you are passing and defined the using of it.

Like this:

```
@model ViewModel.MyModel
```

Razor represent a concret syntax, you cannot use it like javascript dynamic, you have to have it pre-define otherwise the razor compiler has no knowledge of the type you are using and does not know if such property exists.

**UPDATE**

On the second thought there is a way around it, use Viewbag it is dynamic and is meant for it. However, do be careful make sure the properties exist on it before usage.

Comment: But you cannot pass two different models right like that right?

Comment: Two separate models and define them, I am afraid not. Razor uses the concept of ViewModels which defines all objects that should be in a view. @NielsStenden Updated my answer.

Comment: so importing to models like this: model.model1 model.model2 wont work? U have any suggestions how to solve this problem than? Maybe create 2 different views or something?

Comment: Well as far as I understood you want a single view. If you create two separate views, you can use two separate models, however in both cases you would need to define which type you are using in each view.

Comment: I've tried using ViewBag, I've passed model1 into my view and model 2 in as a list in my ViewBag, how do call the syntax of my ViewBag in a TextBoxFor element?

Comment: @ViewBag.YourValue

Comment: Please see updated topic, i've added my attempt to use ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two models to pass in the view. But you can look into `ViewData`. It is an `Dictionary<string, object>`. You can try `ViewData["Model2"] = Model2;` in your controller and in the view you need to cast it like this `Model2 model2 = (Model2)ViewData["Model2"]`.

Edit: Mistakenly used ViewBag instead of ViewData.

Comment: Hi, please see my updated version. I've added my attempt to use ViewBag.

Comment: @NielsStenden ``@Html.TextBoxFor`` is used for your model strongly typed properties only. You can use ``@Html.TextBox`` only..